# A lot of requests in PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql

I am using Django and Python.

I call `ps -aux`:

```
postgres 46214  2.4  0.4 252824 139052 ?       Ss   15:24   0:07 postgres: postgres mydb [local] SELECT
postgres 46216  1.7  0.4 252664 136680 ?       Ss   15:24   0:04 postgres: postgres mydb [local] SELECT
...
```

I get so many such lines (> 10). Also, communication to my database through the `/admin` page takes very long.

Killing the processes does not work - they come back after some time.

As a consequence, I cannot see the database, because the request takes very long and times out.

Can anybody help? Has anybody encountered that before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must find the program running on your machine that connects to the database and runs all these `SELECT` statements.

Then you can stop it or throttle it so that it does not bring the server to its knees.

If you connect to the database with `psql`, you can query `pg_stat_activity` and find out what queries are being executed. That may help you to find out what program it could be.

Comment: Thank you very much, i found spy app :)